# How to treat slightly different types as the same in C++?

Tags: c++

I have two `priority_queues` - a `minheap` and a `maxheap`:

```
priority_queue<int> maxheap;
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minheap;
```

Later in the code, I need to `pop()` from whichever heap is larger:

```c++
(maxheap.size() > minheap.size() ? maxheap : minheap).pop()
```

This line generates an error:

```
error: incompatible operand types ('priority_queue<[2 * ...], (default) std::less<int>>' and 'priority_queue<[2 * ...], greater<int>>')
```

Apparently due to the different comparator making `maxheap` and `minheap`'s type different.

Is there a way around this?  Clearly these two types are highly compatible, so it's very useful to be able to treat them as the same.

Comment: `operator?:` requires that 2nd and 3rd arg are compatible. But in your case they are not. `maxheap.size() > minheap.size() ? maxheap.pop() : minheap.pop()` will probably work. (`pop()` returns `void` if I remember right.)

Comment: To quote Fred Picker, "different isn't the same". And my addition is that "slightly different" is simply "different".

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, gentlemen. I should mention I am used to duck-typed languages like Python, where `(foo if cond else bar).qux()` would be valid even if `foo` and `bar` are of completely different types, as long as they both support a `qux()` method.

Comment: templates support (kind of) duck typing but template instances don't. In your case, it's the latter. ;-)

Comment: Embrace the strict type system. Leave the ducks behind 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the *ternary operator* requires both objects to have a *common type*, which is not the case because the two types you mentioned are not related (neither by inheritance, nor by being convertible to one another).

Just change your code to:

```
if (maxheap.size() > minheap.size())
{
    maxheap.pop();
}
else
{
    minheap.pop();
}
```

---

> Clearly these two types are highly compatible

These two types satisfy a simple concept of exposing a `.pop()` method, but they're not related.

> so it's very useful to be able to treat them as the same

Templates and concepts can help you with that, but there's no shorthand notation for a tiny template that behaves like a ternary operator. The best you can get is:

```
pick(a, b, [](const auto& a, const auto& b)
{
    return a.size() > b.size();
},
[](auto&& x)
{
    x.pop()
});
```

Where `pick` is something like (rough, needs forwarding and untested):

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename Predicate, typename F>
void pick(A&& a, B&& b, Predicate&& predicate, F&& f)
{
    if (predicate(a, b))
    {
        f(a);
    }
    else 
    {
        f(b);
    }
}
```

But the amount of boilerplate defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Indeed I was looking for a concise way to have (effectively) Python-style duck-typing in C++. Since all it does in this case is save me some typing (save me the need to type `.pop()` twice), then the extra boilerplate - while informative - isn't appropriate.